# Sum of Factors and the Phi Function

Tags: number-theory

Let $A$ be a positive integer. Let $B$ be the sum of the positive factors of $A$. Let $C$ be the number of integers that is relatively prime to $B$. Is $\frac{C}{A}$ bounded up? (meaning that there is a $k$ that $\frac{C}{A}<k$ always holds?

I am thinking of splitting $B$ into the various expressions in the form $1+p+p^2+...+p^k$, and noting that $\phi{(ab)}<\phi{(a)}\phi{(b)}$. Then if we prove that the sequence $1+p$, $1+p+p^2$, etc. will always yield a prime, then we are done.

Comment: Here are a few numbers. For $A=4$, the ratio is $3/2$. $A=16$ gives $15/8$. $A=36$ gives $2$. $A=144$ gives $5/2$. $A=576$ gives $21/8$.

Comment: It seems to not be bounded...

Comment: Any thoughts/questions about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In the usual notations, the question is whether $${\phi(\sigma(n))\over n}$$ is bounded above. Mąkowski and Schinzel, On the functions $\phi(n)$ and $\sigma(n)$, Colloq. Math. 13 (1964) 95–99, MR0173660 (30 #3870) (and reprinted in Volume 2 of Schinzel's Selecta, 890-894), prove that it is not. They first prove

Lemma 1. If $a$ is an integer $>1$ and $N(a,p)=(a^p-1)/(a-1)$, then $$\lim_{p\to\infty}{\phi(N(a,p))\over N(a,p)}=\lim_{p\to\infty}{\sigma(N(a,p))\over N(a,p)}=1$$

The proof is elementary.

Then for any $M$ they take $t$ such that $$\prod_{i=1}^t{p_i\over p_i-1}>M$$ and put successively $a=p_1,p_2,\dots,p_t$ in Lemma 1. Then if you put $n=n(p,t)=\prod_{i=1}^tp_i^{p-1}$, they show that you get $$\limsup_{p\to\infty}{\phi(\sigma(n))\over n}>M$$

I'm leaving out a lot of calculations here, you'll have to consult the paper to see the details, but it's not that lengthy or hard to follow.

For $n\le1,000,000$, the maximum value of the quotient is $2821/810=3.483\dots$, attained at $n=291600$.

Comment: Should your product for $n(p, t)$ be of $p_i^{p_i-1}$?

Comment: I don't think so. $i$ is a dummy variable, $p$ is a genuine argument of the function $n(p,t)$, and we take a limsup on $p$. And it's $p$ in the Makowski-Schinzel paper.

Comment: Ok. My mistake.